# Access NSLayoutConstraint in UITableView cellForRowAtIndexPath method?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, constraints

I've used an identifier for a constraint which I added in a subview of a prototype cell, created using AutoLayout. I try to access the constraint using the identifier like this:

```
let myConstraint:NSLayoutConstraint = cellSubview.constraints.filter({ (constraint:NSLayoutConstraint) -> Bool in
            if constraint.identifier == "myIdentifier" {
                return true
            }
            return false
        }).first!
```

At runtime the app crashes because it unexpectedly found nil. This is obviously because of the force unwrapped constraint which doesn't exist in the filtered constraint array. In the debug console I checked how many constraints were in the array: even though I added over 30 constraints to the subview in AutoLayout, it shows that the constraint array contains 0 constraints. I assume this is because the constraints of cell subviews haven't been loaded yet when the `cellForRow atIndexPath` method is called. I also tried moving all my cell configuration code to `willDisplayCell` but I had the exact same result. Does anyone know if it's possible to access a constraint of a cell subview in one of these two delegate methods? The weirdest thing is that the constraints of the cell's content view ARE loaded when these methods are called, but the subviews constraints aren't.

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't want to access a cell subview until at least `table(_ makeViewForRow)`.

That being said, you should probably put this code inside the CellView class inside viewDidLoad(). This will ensure that all your IB outlets are instantiated and loaded. Also it will help keep all CellView logic contained with the CellView instance.

Comment: I'm not using a CellView class. I created the entire cell view in my storyboard and I'm accessing all of the subviews with tags (`cell.viewWithTag(tagNumber)`). I think it's bad practice to use IB outlets on subviews inside a cell's view since I usually don't want to make every cell's view identical, and I want to configure every cell's view depending on what row the cell's in. Long story short, there's nothing cell or table view related to configure in viewDidLoad(). All of it happens in the table view's delegate methods.

Comment: If you make your own Cell class you can change the content based off row in table(_ makeViewForRow) by setting up the cell with makeWithIdentifer and accessing the cells attributes, or you can define the different types of cells you want by making multiple cell subclasses then based on row return a different cell in table(_ makeViewForRow)